# Visual Studio is telling me I'm missing a ';'. (New to C++)

Tags: c++

Header file:

```
#ifndef DYN_H
#define DYN_H

int max_of_array(int* arry, int arraysize);

#endif
```

Source file:

```
#include "dyn.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std

int max_of_array(int* arry, int arraysize){
    if (arry == NULL) {
         cout << "Invalid Array" << endl;
         exit(0);
    }

    int max_value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraysize; i++) {
        if (arry[i] > max_value) max_value = arry[i];
    }

    delete[] arry;

    return max_value;
}
```

It's probably something stupid, but what am I doing wrong?

Visual studio suggests that a ';' is missing at line 5 of the source code and 'int' is underlined.

Comment: try `;` after `using namespace std`

Comment: `using` is a statement.  It needs to be terminated with a semicolon.  (But better, don't use `using namespace std;` and spell out the `std::` everywhere.)

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm actually an idiot

Comment: Everybody did something similar at some point in their career :) But I recommend trying to solve such minimal issues yourself before posting on SO though.

Comment: A tool that analyzes the code cannot tell that something is missing (because it cannot read your mind). It signals that the token it founds after  the missing token is not expected there (hence it underlines the `int` keyword in red).

Comment: OT: `delete[] arry;` that is really bad design. A function named `max_of_array`should calculate the max, but not delete the array. What if it was called with an array not allocated with new?

Comment: I don't get it; why are people upvoting this?  It shows a distinct lack of research or effort to resolve

Comment: In general, when a compiler complains about a missing `;`, the line number it gives you is often too *late*. You may have to back up a line or two

Comment: @UKMonkey sometimes it's okay to be nice to beginners so they come back and contribute later when they are no longer beginners

Comment: @RPGillespie Being nice is answering their question.  Upvoting their question however is REWARDING their lack of research.  You'll notice that when you hover over the upvote button it says "shows research effort, is useful and clear" ... while this question is clear, there is no research and there is no use (it's even off topic).   You will notice that these are 'ands' while the down vote button 'ors' these conditions.  Nice has nothing to do with it, it's about stopping SO keeping questions forever that are of no use!

Comment: @UKMonkey Maybe we need to change it from being "upvotes" and "downvotes" to "it helped me" counter representing the number of people the question helped. If it is only useful for 1 person it gets archived, but it if helped others the number will tick up.

As it stands people take downvotes as a personal attack and upvotes as encouragement

Answer (score 4):

It's at line 3, but the compiler continues to read and only finds out it's missing on line 5. Line 3 should read:

```
using namespace std;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the compiler doesn't pin point it down and you need to look at the lines before it. In your case the `using namespace` line